# Codeigniter Custom Controller Receiving 404

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

So I copied the controller file Welcome.php and named it home.php.
I changed the class name from Welcome to Home.

When I go to view it in http://daytodata.net/ci/index.php/home I get a 404?
[image]

Comment: You did not set route correctly. It's placed in config/route.php

Comment: How do I adjust the route? I currently have: $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Comment: `$route['^home$']  = 'home/index';`

Comment: This worked, would I have to do this for all controllers?

Comment: all uri which will not be matched in route will result in 404 error

Comment: So I'll take that as a very technical yes answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try accessing your method using /home/index/ ?

Also you should consider take advantage from routing system:

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: Yes and this worked. The video I'm following must be on an old version?

Comment: in CI, default matching if /action/method/, If this worked, can you approve the answer ?